# Split string by comma delimiter in Redshift

Tags: sql, split, amazon-redshift

I want to transform the column below

```
select config_json from table 

   {"required_capacity": true, "cancelation_time_minutes": 0, "display_no_preference_in_booking": true}
{"feedback": true, "required_capacity": true, "setup_wizard_completed": false, "cancelation_time_minutes": 0, "display_no_preference_in_booking": true}
{"required_capacity": false, "cancelation_time_minutes": 0, "display_no_preference_in_booking": true}
{"required_capacity": true, "setup_wizard_completed": true, "cancelation_time_minutes": 0, "display_no_preference_in_booking": true}
{"feedback": true, "required_capacity": true, "setup_wizard_completed": false, "cancelation_time_minutes": 0, "display_no_preference_in_booking": true}
```

into a table format like this:

```
required_capacity     cancelation_time_minutes       display_no_preference_in_booking  ...
true                              0                         true                       ...
true                              0                         true                       ...
false                             0                         true                       ...
```

So far, I first remove the {} sign from the column, and plan to split the column by delimiter ','.

```
SELECT string_to_array(config_json, ',') as abcd
FROM  (select config_json, regexp_replace(config_json, '[{} ]','') as no_curly_bracket --remove the {} sign 
        from table ) a
```

The error message says:

```
 Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redshift doesn't support arrays or table valued functions.  You can extract each column separately:

```
select regexp_substr(config_json, '"required_capacity": ([^,]+)', 1, 1, 'e') as required_capacity,
       regexp_substr(config_json, '"cancelation_time_minutes": ([^,]+)', 1, 1, 'e') as cancelation_time_minutes,
       . . .
```

Comment: could you please add the one for characters as well? [A-Z] does not seem to work.

Comment: @Luc . . . I'm not sure what you mean.  The `([^,]+)` should pick up any string of characters up to the following comma.

Comment: understood. In my case, I have > 50 dictionary key-value pairs. Do you have an idea how to achieve the same purpose without manually typing the column names?

Comment: also, here, you are referring to config_json as the column to use, instead of the one without curly bracket. As a result, some values contain }, for example "true}" . In one column, I have values such as TRUE, FALSE, true}, true, false}, false..
could you probably suggest how to fix that?